# Display all products from all sellers using data binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a mobile application using Xamarin.Forms to enable users to add sellers and products. 
I have three classes:

- Seller: a registered user who wishes to sell products.
- Product: an item that the seller wants to sell.
- Sellers: has a property to contain a list of sellers, CurrentSellerID and CurrentProductID. The CurrentSellerID and CurrentProductID are counters to handle unique numbers for seller’s ID and products’ ID. Whenever a new seller and a new product are added, these counters should increase and assign to the correspond IDs.

Seller class:

```
public class Seller
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int SellerID { get; set; }
        public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
        public Seller(string inName, string inMobile, string inEmail, int inID)
        {
            Name = inName;
            MobileNumber = inMobile;
            Email = inEmail;
            SellerID = inID;
            ProductList = new List<Product>();
        }
    }
```

Product class:

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Product(int inID, string inTitle, string inImage, double inPrice, int inQuantity, string inDesc)
        {
            ProductID = inID;
            Title = inTitle;
            ImageName = inImage;
            Price = inPrice;
            Quantity = inQuantity;
            Description = inDesc;
        }

    }
}
```

Sellers class (contains a method for generating test data):

```
 public class Sellers
    {
        public static int CurrentSellerID = 0;
        public static int CurrentProductID = 0;

        public Sellers()
        {
            SellerList = new ObservableCollection<Seller>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Seller> SellerList;
        public static Sellers GenerateTestData()
        {
            string[] firstNames = new string[] { "Rob", "Jim" };
            string[] lastsNames = new string[] { "Smith", "Jones" };
            string[] mobileNumbers = new string[] { "07492941804", "07402276152" };
            string[] emailAddress = new string[] { "robSmith@gmail.com", "jimJones@gmail.com" };

            string[] productTitles = new string[] { "Mobile", "RAM", "CPU", "HDD", "SSD", "RAM" };
            string[] imageNames = new string[] { "img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png" };
            double[] productPrice = new double[] { 100.00, 75.00, 328.25, 43.50, 65.00, 100 };
            int[] productQuantity = new int[] { 100, 20, 10, 5, 30, 60 };
            string[] productDesc = new string[] { "iPhone X, 128GB Storage, Black", "DDR4-3000 MHz", "Intel i5-9600K", "1TB Hard Drive", "250GB SSD, 500MB/s", "DDR4-2666MHz" };

            Sellers result = new Sellers();

            string name = firstNames[0] + lastsNames[0];
            Seller newSeller = new Seller(name, mobileNumbers[0], emailAddress[0], Sellers.CurrentSellerID);
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                Product newProduct = new Product(Sellers.CurrentProductID, productTitles[x], imageNames[x], productPrice[x], productQuantity[x], productDesc[x]);
                newSeller.ProductList.Add(newProduct);
                CurrentProductID++;
            }
            result.SellerList.Add(newSeller);

            CurrentSellerID++;

            return result;        
        }
    }
```

In the App class, an instance is created and test data generation function is called:

```
 public static Sellers ActiveSellersList;

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ActiveSellersList = Sellers.GenerateTestData();
        }
```

I have a page that should use data binding to display all products. This is called "ViewProductsPage". A ListView (lstProductDetails) is used to show the products in the list.

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstProductDetails">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" HorizontalOptions="Start"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 600, 50 " Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical"
VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text = "{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" TextColor="#f35e20"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                                    <Label Text = "{Binding Price}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Blue"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100, 35, 200, 25"/>
                                    <Label Text = "{Binding Quantity}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Blue"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100, 35, 200, 25"/>
                                    <Label Text = "{Binding Description}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Blue"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100, 35, 200, 25"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

The problem I have is binding all of the products. I am unsure how to display the ProductList. This is the code I have in the constructor of the ViewProductsPage.

```
this.lstProductDetails.ItemsSource = App.ActiveSellersList.ProductList;
```

This code does not work because sellers does not contain a definition of ProductList.

How can I display the list of products from all sellers? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually:

```
this.lstProductDetails.ItemsSource = App.ActiveSellersList.SellerList.SelectMany(s => s.ProductList);
```

In your case.